# how to go from JAXB to BSON for Mongo DB

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

Is there a direct way to go from JAXB object to BSON for Mongo DB?  Do i have to first convert to JSON and then to BSON?  Seems like a lot of overhead.

Comment: You should accept helpful answers to your questions.

Comment: How would you encode a JSON string to BSON? I can't see an API for that. There still doesn't seem to be a solution for your specific problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use an ORM like morphia.
Then map the java class to its representation in mongo.
This is probably easiest & cleanest.

Going through JSON would be very slow since it involves converting back & forth to text.
Worst case you can convert the java object to an equivalent BasicDBObject representation, which you can then use directly with the driver.

Comment: was hoping there was something which automagically can take JAXB and stuff it into Mongo.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I realize it's more than 8 years since you asked the question. But I've written JaxBson which should do the trick.

If you still are interested then see [the project on GitLab](https://gitlab.com/qnizyx/jaxbson). There's a TL;DR section in the README.md that should explain the workings.

The artifact is named `jaxbson` and it is on the Maven Central Repository.